# Image upload issue using Multipartentity in Nougat 7.0 and higher version

Tags: android, android-studio, image-uploading, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I have used the below code to capture the images from camera and stored into the device. Then i have uploaded those files by pressing button using multipartentity.These code works fine all the version but failed works on the Nougat version 7.0 + higher versions,

```
String serverResponseCode = uploadFiles(path.next());
public String uploadFiles(String sourceFileUri)
    {
        String responseString = null;
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/upload.php");
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity();
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            entity.addPart("username",new StringBody(Username));
            httppost.setEntity(entity);    
            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();    
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {                   
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            }
            else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode; }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

I have used the below PHP code in server side., These code created the folder but image did not available.

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
//$target_path = "uploads/";
$year = date("Y-m-d");
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';

 $target_path=$year."/".$username."/"; 
//If the directory doesn't already exists.
 if(!is_dir($target_path))
 {
     //Create our directory.
    mkdir($target_path,0777,true);
 }

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'Merchandise' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) 
{
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    //$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    //$website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //$response['email'] = $email;
    //$response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
           $response['error'] = true;
               $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Can you  share your error log

Comment: I did not get any error., I have processed that request using php in server. Using Php i have created a folder and stored the file. The code created the folder but the image did not appears in it.

Comment: Did you check API working in postman?

Comment: make sure your uploaded file's extension is allowed in server and uploaded file size does not exceed server file size limit (some servers have it at 2mb)

Comment: yes, it is working. I have upload the images along with some data. Those data gets inserted into the table but the image only not received. Image does not received on server while upload using android 7.0 and higher version only.,

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileProvider`

```
String serverResponseCode = uploadFiles(path.next());
public String uploadFiles(String sourceFileUri)
    {

    File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "external_files");
    imagePath.mkdir();
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath.getPath(), "test.jpg");

    // Write data in your file

    Uri fileUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), imageFile);
        String responseString = null;
        try
        {

            File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/upload.php");
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity();
            File sourceFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            entity.addPart("username",new StringBody(Username));
            httppost.setEntity(entity);    
            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();    
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {                   
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            }
            else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode; }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

For more details [Read this](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html)

Comment: I have faced the below exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: i am getting image path from storage directory you have to set manually.